# Gatsby refuses to install all dependencies

Tags: gatsby

[image]I don't know what's wrong with gatsby on my pc, seems I didn't install all dependencies as it should be. Please someone should help me.

npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.23.2 install script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: Please provide a little more information, it's extremely unlikely that anyone could guess the issue from this.

Comment: jonrsharpe I think that explains it all right

Comment: Don't post text as pictures.

Comment: ok jonsharpe noted. I wanna start a gatsby project but its saying cannot find module "sharp"

Comment: so in other words is not loading the plugins finish

Comment: Scroll up and find the first error. The text you posted just indicates that there's an error earlier in the log, and I can't read the image to see if it's in there.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you tried to delete and reinstalle node_modules in your project ? And for Windows, it's better to use cmder.exe unlike default cmd tools.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like last version of Sharp working on 32bits environment is v0.11.4 and you're trying to install 0.23.2. according to this issue: 
https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/379

and Gatsby documentation:

> Some plugins which depend on native NPM dependencies require the Node
>   x64 build of Node.js. If you’re struggling to install
>   gatsby-plugin-sharp, try installing Node x64 and removing node_modules
>   and running npm install.

Also, you could try to follow those recommendations from Gatsby documentation, like installing windows build tool:

> The recommended way to setup your build environment on Windows is to
>   install the windows-build-tools package by running npm install
>   windows-build-tools -g on an admin PowerShell console

Source:
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-on-windows/

It should resolve many of your problems.